# NSMutableArray becomes empty when I call any IBAction

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

Please help me i have a `NSMutableArray` which contains data until `viewDidLoad` is finished.

When I click any button I try to get the data in it and it just disappears.

Comment: Can you please post your code so we can see where you're going wrong?

Comment: thnx Ashley the comment below contained the solution to my problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you created your array with a variant of `[NSMutableArray array]` it will be autoreleased. Assuming `myArray` is a property of your class, you should use

```
myArray = [[NSMutableArray] alloc] init]; //or initWithCapacity, etc.
```

If you still use reference counting, you need to add `[myArray retain];` unless it is already retained in the `@property` declaration and release it in `viewDidUnload:`.